# create youtube playlist from array of links

Tags: php, arrays, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

hi can i make a php function where i can pass a array of youtube links and it creates a playlist in youtube for a certain user, i have read youtube docs but still can not figure out.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Adding_a_Playlist_Video
on the doc it displays the following code.

```
    $newPlaylist = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry();
$newPlaylist->summary = $yt->newDescription()->setText('description of my new playlist');
$newPlaylist->title = $yt->newTitle()->setText('title of my new playlist');
// post the new playlist
$postLocation = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/playlists';
try {
  $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylist, $postLocation);
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm hardly an expert, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
//Make a loop to go over all of the values within the array
     for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
$postUrl = $playlistToAddTo->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();
// video entry to be added
$videoEntryToAdd = $yt->getVideoEntry($array[i]);

// create a new Zend_Gdata_PlaylistListEntry, passing in the underling DOMElement of the VideoEntry
$newPlaylistListEntry = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry($videoEntryToAdd->getDOM());

// post
try {
  $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylistListEntry, $postUrl);
} catch (Zend_App_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

The variable `$array` should obviously be a one dimensional array that contains the ytvideos 'IDs'. Hope that helped.